# Open second python interpreter in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, interpreter

How would I open a second python interpreter in emacs? I am using emacs 24.3 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have opened the SQL interpreter/program via a prefix argument of 2. I tried this with python and it did not work.

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome. The mode in my current python interpreter buffer says: `Inferior Python: run Shell-Compile` I have downloaded python-mode 6.10 from ELPA the emacs package manager.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: isn't it usually just `M-x run-python`?

Comment: That takes me to my already open python interpreter. My already open python interpreter is running a program that takes a long time to process...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M-x describe-function` (RET) `run-python`:

> run-python is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `python.el'.
>
> (run-python &optional CMD NOSHOW NEW)
>
> Run an inferior Python process, input and output via buffer *Python*.
>   CMD is the Python command to run.  NOSHOW non-nil means don't show the
>   buffer automatically.
>
> Interactively, a prefix arg means to prompt for the initial Python
>   command line (default is `python-command').
>
> A new process is started if one isn't running attached to
>   `python-buffer', or if called from Lisp with non-nil arg NEW.
>   Otherwise, if a process is already running in`python-buffer', switch
>   to that buffer.
>
> ...

In the `*scratch*` buffer:

```
(run-python nil nil 't)
```

That will give you a new Inferior Python process.

You could code up a new interactive emacs command in your `.emacs` file, something like:

```
(defun my-run-python ()
  (interactive)
  (run-python nil nil 't))
```

Comment: How do I create the *scratch* buffer if I already deleted it?

Comment: Why delete it?  `C-x b *scratch*`, and then say yes to create it.  Alternatively, I think you can do `M-x lisp-interaction-mode` in any buffer to make it into an equivalent buffer.  BTW, put your cursor at the end of your last right paren in your lisp expression and `C-x C-e` to evaluate the expression.

Comment: That didn't work... It just evaluates to `nil` in the mini-buffer.

Comment: `(run-python nil 't 't)` worked for modern emacs

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>python</kbd>

BTW your python-mode version is outdated.
Recommend to fetch a new one doing

```
bzr branch lp:python-mode
```

or visit

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus `el-get`, `https://github.com/dimitri/el-get` distributes a reasonably updated version. Also you might replace old python-mode.el by hand.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus An emacs package manager, check out the link given.